# how to provide user roles and permission in jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am creating a community project. The concept is similar to Reddit and Facebook group. a basic user only can post in a group and also can create a group. but on the group page**(URL ex: `gorup.jsp?groupid=10`)**, I can't define the user roles and permission.if the user not joined in that group he will see only join option. if he joined then he can post and on the other side if he the group owner, he can do all perform.

for this, I created two tables.

**group_Table**

```
id(pk), group_name, group_description, userId(fk)
```

**group_members_table**

```
id(pk), group_id(fk), userId(fk))
```

how to come out for this problem?

Comment: What is user_id?

Comment: userId is the user who logged in. in group_table admin_id is the user id who logged in or who created the group.

Comment: Why would that be logged in the group table?

Comment: I am defining that user as admin.

Comment: I'm confused. Clearly, you've edited your question.

Comment: yes, I am sorry. it's related to JSP, servlet, and MySQL. I have created the table and I don't how to set permission for user or admin in the JSP page. I mean In the JSP page what admin can do and what ordinary user can do? I can't think how to set permission for that.

Answer (score 1):

May be:

```
Group {id, name, user_id}
User {user_id, name, group_id}
Permission {id, group_id, user_id, permission_type-full/half/admin/user/super_user}
```

Comment: Why would group appear in user?